# I want to parse capital cities from a webpage and print them in a terminal when the user inputs countries

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

Webpage: https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm
I want to parse the webpage using Beautiful Soup
For example, if the user inputs the United Kingdom, the program must print London.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm")
c = r.text


soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
data = soup.find("table", id="anyid")
rows = data.find_all("tr")
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: And what have you tried?  There are a billion examples showing how to use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @TimRoberts I parse countries and cities from websites, but now I don't know what to do

Comment: I don't know what that means.  If you have code to parse websites, then you have 99% of your code already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so what you have is 90% of it.  Why couldn't you pick up from there?  You have a list of all the rows.  So, for each row, you find the `<td>` elements which have the information.  The first td text has the country, the second td text has the capital.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://geographyfieldwork.com/WorldCapitalCities.htm")
c = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
data = soup.find("table", id="anyid")
rows = data.find_all("tr")
capitals = {}
for row in rows:
    parts = row.find_all("td")
    if parts:
        capitals[parts[0].text] = parts[1].text
print(capitals)
```

Comment: I added this code at the and  `country = str(input("Enter country : "))
print(capitals[country])`  thanks for help